# Aptana 3 installation error first time install

Tags: html, file, logging, metadata, aptana3

Hi there install seem to be ok, but when I boot up Aptana, I get a .metadata/log error.... I'm not the top genius when it comes to logs:  Here it is:

```
        !SESSION 2019-10-09 03:33:25.653 -----------------------------------------------
        eclipse.buildId=unknown
         java.version=13
         java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
         BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_CA
         Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/kraz/.eclipse_keyring
         Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/kraz/.eclipse_keyring

        !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-10-09 03:33:29.091
        !MESSAGE Application error
        !STACK 1
         org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:          javax/annotation/PostConstruct
         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
         at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
         at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
         at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:126)
         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
```

I have tried to set up Apatana 2.0 long time ago... but still have not got 3 to work properly... and type of help would be appreciated.
Steve